# Laravel check if a string contains a word from a database

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a table that contains the list of employees, I have a string that can contain the names of employees.

I created a SQL query that displays the names of employees who are already on the string. but I can not translate it into query Laravel.

how can I write this request in Laravel?

```
SELECT title from employes WHERE "my string" like concat("%", title, "%")
```

Comment: How does that string look like, separated by comma or something? Best bet would be to explode that string and use a loop to check for the exact username, not using `like`.

Comment: quoting OP: `"string of character : "the employee Antoine is on leave, he must be replaced by Lionel.... Employees table: Antoine, Lionel ...... how can you recover these names !?"`

Answer (score 4):

Your check is inverted, which makes it needlessly complex to write, you should do `WHERE title LIKE '%my string%'` instead.

Then in Laravel:

```
Employee::where('title', 'like', '%' . $myString . '%')->get();
```

Comment: I think OP meant that the string `"my string"` will have many names...

Comment: sorry this query does not give anything! example:

string of character : "the employee Antoine is on leave, he must be replaced by Lionel....

Employees table: Antoine, Lionel ......

how can you recover these names !?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DB` facade and execute your SQL query in your controller as follow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all of the employes.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $myString = 'test';
        $employees = DB::select('SELECT title from employees WHERE title like "%'.$myString.'%"', [$myString]);

        return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

In the laravel, you should use following query

```
$string = "the employee Antoine is on leave, he must be replaced by Lionel";

$findstring = explode(' ', $string); 

$emp = Employee::where(function ($q) use ($findstring) {
       foreach ($findstring as $value) {
            $q->orWhere('title', 'like', "%{$value}%");
       }
       })->select('title')->get();

dd($emp);
```

Comment: neither one to give a good result, it's simple this query SQL SELECT title from employes WHERE "my string" like concat("%", title, "%") . gave me a good result, I'm looking for how to convert in laravel?

Comment: @visulo Yes, you are right. In SQL query working. But when in laravel query builder use above example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = $request->input('message');
if($message) {
    $findstring = explode(' ', $message); 
    $excluded = DB::table('word_list')->where(function ($q) use ($findstring) {
        foreach ($findstring as $value) {
            $q->orWhere('words', 'like', "%{$value}");
        }
    })->select('words')->first();
}
if($excluded != null) {
    return response()->json(['success'=>false,'excluded'=>$excluded,'message'=>' This is an excluded message','status'=>'message not send']);
} else {
    broadcast(new NewMessage($message));
    return response()->json(['success'=>true,'message'=>$message,'status'=>'message sent']);
}
```